# Remove specific key from associative array from within a condition

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I ran into a coding situation where i'd prefer to keep a certain condition as compact as possible:

```
// $data and $control are arrays
if($data==$control || ($someBool && $data==$control))
    return $c;
```

Of course this condition makes no sense that way. My goal is to remove a key from `$control` in the last part of my condition, before comparing it against `$data`.

Of course it could be done like this:

```
function chopByKey(array $arr, $key){
    if(!isset($arr[$key]))
        return $arr;
    unset($arr[$key]);
    return $arr;
}
```

And rewrite the condition:

```
if($data==$control || ($someBool && $data==chopByKey($control, 'someKey') ))
    return $c;
```

**Please note**

I am looking for a solution that i can use within my condition, not any solution that requires any additional step *ahead* of the condition or the definition of a custom function, be it anonymous or not.

**My question is**

Is there any more elegant way to do this, without defining a new custom function?

If yes, how?

Comment: How about a closure? http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: That's generally a good idea but given the fact that its not an overly specific move, i don't think using an anonymous function would be the way to go. I'll edit my question though to make my point more clear. Thx!

Comment: Seems to me that what you're doing is a pretty compact and efficient way - why would you want anything else? Code readability is fine, it does the job...?

Comment: I'm merely attempting to learn. Over the years, step by step, i have found gems and tricks in PHP that were previously hidden to me. I am hoping to make a similar discovery in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with the following line:

```
$control = array('hello' => 'world', 'foo' => 'bar');
$data = array('hello' => 'world');
$someBool = true;

if ($data == $control || $someBool && $data == array_diff_key($control, array('foo' => 0))) {
```

Side effect is that `$control` is not modified by the condition.

Comment: Great approach! `$control` shouldn't be modified anyway. I wouldn't have passed it to my helper function by reference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is:

```
$checkControl = $control;
if ($someBool) unset($checkControl['somekey']);

if ($checkControl == $data) {
```

It requires 2 extra lines, but the whole is very readable.

But it doesn't really answer your question... If you want it in 1 line, you might want to check `array_diff_assoc()`:

```
$diff = array_diff_assoc($control, $data);
if (!$diff || ($someBool && array_keys($diff) == array('somekey'))) {
```

It's not very readable and probably not very efficient.

Comment: Very nice approach! Thanks for the warning, too. I am not looking for efficiency or readability. Given these criteria, this seems like a good solution.

Comment: Good question. I actually had to try a few things and look at the PHP manual for `array_diff_assoc()`. I hardly use it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may look elegant:

```
<?php
    $data = array(
    "one" => "1",
    "two" => "2"
    );
    $control  = array(
    "one" => "1",
    "two" => "2",
    "three" => "3"
    );
    if ($data==$control || ($someBool && $data==array_slice($control,0,count($control)-1))
    {
        return $c;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You've got to be kidding me.

Answer (score 0):

As for your function, I'd have done it like this:

```
function chopByKey(array $arr, $key){
  if(array_key_exists($key,$arr)){
    unset($arr[$key]);
    return $arr;
  }
  // depending on your desired result, either return $arr or return false here.
  return $arr;
}
```